# Why is gulp compiling my SCSS files in alphabetical order?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I've never had this happen before, and I usually use the same gulpfile. All of my SCSS files are compiling alphabetically, which means things aren't being overridden properly. Here's the compiling message. (note, I've blacked out my client's name)

[image]

This is my style.scss file

```
//Mixins
@import 'mixins';

//Globals
@import 'config';
@import 'global/global';

//Header
@import 'global/header';

//Company
@import 'company/leadership';


//Social buttons
@import 'social/social_buttons';

@import 'company/contact-us';

@import 'company/events-listing';

//Active Data Fabric tweak
@import 'active/active-data-fabric';

// News CPT Single
@import 'news/single';

//Resource Listing
@import 'resources/listing';

//Resource Single
@import 'resources/single';

//Products
@import 'products/products';

//Featured Testimonials
@import 'featured_testimonials/index';

//Videos Page
@import 'videos/index';

//Header Override
@import 'resources/header';

//Support Page
@import 'support/overview';

// Careers Page
@import 'company/careers';

//Search Page
@import 'search/index.scss';

// Import Views
@import 'views/home';
```

And here is my gulpfile

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifycss = require('gulp-cssnano');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return sass('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(''))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./scss'))
            .pipe(notify({ message: 'Wait for it....wait for it!!!' }));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss',['css']);
});
```

Like I said, this has never happened before, so I'm at a loss. Shouldn't the files compile according to the order specified in the style.scss file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `**/*.scss` wildcard picks up files alphabetically. Since the `**` recurses to the bottom of the directory structure, it returns the directories alphabetically, with the files in each also sorted alphabetically.

That's the expected output of the wildcard.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. I'm a front end dev, so I get lost with that stuff. I mainly copied and pasted the gulpfile from a tutorial. How would I fix it to follow the compiling order outlined in my style.scss file?

Comment: Oh nvm I got it! I just replaced the **/*.scss with style.scss and it compiled correctly. Thanks for setting me on the path!

Comment: You might be able to just change it to `style.scss` and it will import everything as you have it there. Glad to hear it worked!